# How to connect to Windows RDP and delegate authentication to a (reverse) proxy?

Tags: authentication, windows, proxy, rdp

Looking for the following setup:

Client connects to Windows RDP server through proxy server. The client is in public network hence can't send username/password for logon. The proxy server in between should authenticate to RDP server and open a session and secure the access to RDP server.

Or how can the client send login information (certificate) securely?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a RDP reverse proxy, not just a TCP proxy. There are plenty of software providing that functionality (in different forms), free and paid.